# When I install gitLab on the OSX have the error :Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 502

Tags: macos, gitlab

I follow this step to install gitLab https://github.com/WebEntity/Installation-guide-for-GitLab-on-OS-X, but I get the error:Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 502

[image: this is the terminal result]
this is the terminal result

Double-check Application Status

The last step：{To make sure you didn't miss anything run a more thorough check with:

sudo su git
. ~/.profile
cd ~/gitlab/
bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
If all items are green, then congratulations on successfully installing GitLab!}

bash-3.2$ bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 2.6.9 ? ... OK (2.6.9)

Repo base directory exists? ... yes

Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no

Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
hooks directories in repos are links: ... can't check, you have no projects

Running /Users/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check

***Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 502

gitlab-shell self-check failed

Try fixing it:

Make sure GitLab is running;

Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:

sudo -u git -H editor /Users/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml

Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.***

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... no

Try fixing it:

sudo -u git -H RAILS_ENV=production bin/background_jobs start

For more information see:

doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"

see log/sidekiq.log for possible errors

Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking Reply by email ...

Reply by email is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking Reply by email ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Git configured with autocrlf=input? ... yes

Database config exists? ... yes

Database is SQLite ... no

All migrations up? ... yes

Database contains orphaned GroupMembers? ... no

GitLab config exists? ... yes

GitLab config outdated? ... no

Log directory writable? ... yes

Tmp directory writable? ... yes

Uploads directory setup correctly? ... no

Try fixing it:

sudo -u git mkdir -m 750 /Users/git/gitlab/public/uploads

For more information see:

doc/install/installation.md in section "GitLab"

Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Init script exists? ... yes

Init script up-to-date? ... yes

projects have namespace: ... can't check, you have no projects

Redis version >= 2.8.0? ... yes

Ruby version >= 2.1.0 ? ... yes (2.1.7)

Your git bin path is "/usr/local/bin/git"

Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (2.7.0)

Active users: 0

Checking GitLab ... Finished

I am a novice with the server

Comment: Running /Users/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 502
gitlab-shell self-check failed
  Try fixing it:
  Make sure GitLab is running;
  Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:
  sudo -u git -H editor /Users/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Comment: Please copy/paste the terminal result as text rather than as an image. This will help others to see your question.

Comment: Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  sudo -u git -H RAILS_ENV=production bin/background_jobs start
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
  see log/sidekiq.log for possible errors
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Comment: Check https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/124

Comment: @yorammi I don't know what to do and how to do it.

Comment: @yorammi When I visit 127.0.0.1, show 502 Gateway Bad

Comment: In the post he solved the issue as such:
I solved this problem by changing the user and group of nginx to root

Comment: How did you change the user and group of nginx to root?

Comment: @MichaelLong I don't know，Did you find the answer

Comment: @yorammi How can I change the user and group of nginx to root?

Comment: use the chown command:


sudo chown root:root <path-to-nginx-folder>

Comment: @yorammi I change the user and group of nginx to root but the problem is not solved

Comment: @田益华 I'm having the same issue too. Were you ever able to resolve it?